# Where to locate my view models in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I currently have a Models folder (the one created by the MVC project template) in my Web application project, and this is where I have placed all my view models.  Pure data models are in a separate class library, and then I have a Services project for serving data model entities to the web project.

Now I am wondering if I should not maybe move my view models and mapping code into the services project.  Would this be an improvement on my current structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ViewModels should remain in view, they are not part of the domain model, something specific to the view only. You can check out AutoMapper which can handle mapping view specific objects...

Comment: I am actually already using AutoMapper.  Quite the little tool!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's fine the way you have it.  View models should live as close to the view as possible, since they only make sense for the view.  You mapping should happen in your web project because your services layer shouldn't care how its data is being consumed.